# Play: How to remove the fields without value from JSON and create a new JSON with them

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

Given the following JSON:

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "",
  "field3": "value3",
  "field4": ""
}
```

How do I get two distinct JSONs, one containing the fields with value and another one containing the fields without value? Here below is how the final result should look like:

```json
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field3": "value3"
}

{
  "field2": "",
  "field4": ""
}
```

Comment: and just looping through and building two new objects isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have access to the JSON object's fields as a sequence of `(String, JsValue)` pairs and you can filter through them. You can filter out the ones with and without value and use the filtered sequences to construct new `JsObject` objects.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val ls =
  ("field1", JsString("value1")) ::
  ("field2", JsString("")) ::
  ("field3", JsString("value3")) ::
  ("field4", JsString("")) ::
  Nil

val js0 = new JsObject(ls)

def withoutValue(v: JsValue) = v match {
  case JsNull => true
  case JsString("") => true
  case _ => false
}

val js1 = JsObject(js0.fields.filterNot(t => withoutValue(t._2)))
val js2 = JsObject(js0.fields.filter(t => withoutValue(t._2)))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can improve @nietaki solution by using partition function.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val ls =
  ("field1", JsString("value1")) ::
    ("field2", JsString("")) ::
    ("field3", JsString("value3")) ::
    ("field4", JsString("")) ::
    Nil

val js0 = new JsObject(ls)

def withoutValue(v: JsValue) = v match {
  case JsNull => true
  case JsString("") => true
  case _ => false
}

val (js1, js2) = js0.fields.partition(t => withoutValue(t._2))
JsObject(js1)
JsObject(js2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in a one liner:

```
val (js1, js2) = j.fields.partition(_._2 != JsString(""))
println(JsObject(js1))
println(JsObject(js2))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9IeHRZobQsesuzwlq5yOqA)