# JSON Objects null filtering in scala

Tags: json, scala, play-json

I am using `play.api.libs.json` in Scala (2.12.8) to process some json objects. I have for example a JSON string that looks like:

```json
{
  "field1": null,
  "field2": 23,
  "field3": {
    "subfield1": "a",
    "subfield2": null
  },
  "field4": {
    "subfield1": true,
    "subfield2": {
      "subsubfield1": null,
      "subsubfield2": "45"
    },
    "field5": 3
  }
}
```

And I want to filter out every null fields or subfields.

As explained here: [Play: How to remove the fields without value from JSON and create a new JSON with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512942/play-how-to-remove-the-fields-without-value-from-json-and-create-a-new-json-wit)

Doing:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json.{ JsNull, JsObject, JsValue, Json }

val j = Json.parse(myJsonString).as[JsObject]
JsObject(j.fields.filterNot(t => withoutValue(t._2)))

def withoutValue(v: JsValue) = v match {
  case JsNull => true
  case _      => false
}
```

helps me remove the upper level fields: in my case, `field1`

But `field3.subfield2` and `field4.subfield2.subsubfield1` are still present. I want to remove them. Also I should mention that not every subfields can be null at once. Should this happen, I think we could just remove the upper level field. If `field3.subfield1`and `field3.subfield2` are null, we can remove `field3`.

Any idea on how to do this neatly in Scala?

PS: the desired output is:

```json
{
  "field2": 23,
  "field3": {
    "subfield1": "a"
  },
  "field4": {
    "subfield1": true,
    "subfield2": {
      "subsubfield2": "45"
    },
    "field5": 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need it as a JsObject afterwards? You can parse it into a case class that doesn't even have these fields or these fields that are nullable as option and missing or null fields will be parsed as None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a recursive solution. For example:

```
def removeNulls(jsObject: JsObject): JsValue = {
  JsObject(jsObject.fields.collect {
    case (s, j: JsObject) =>
      (s, removeNulls(j))
    case other if (other._2 != JsNull) =>
      other
  })
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/6oHKfGt0SWuaL8KI1EKnZg/1). Output is as expected.